# How to configure http://localhost:9000 to http:/mylocal.loc

Tags: twitter, playframework, localhost

I'm using the Play Framework which uses http://localhost:9000 by default. I'm also trying something with Twitter and it needs to use a callback url for authentication, but Twitter won't accept http://localhost:9000 as a callback URL.

How can I configure my localhost to map to something like http://mylocal.loc, (similar as with an Apache vhost), instead of http://localhost:9000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the URL needed to be entered in the following format:

> http://127.0.0.1:9000/twitter-callback

The above works perfectly as a Twitter callback address.

Twitter isn't trying to access localhost directly, it simply takes the above address as far as I understand, sticks it into the HTTP response header, prompting whichever browser being used to perform a straight forward 302 redirect.

The following blog post had some invaluable information in regards to this question:

http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2009/08/17/how-to-quickly-set-up-a-test-for-twitter-oauth-authentication-from-your-local-machine/

Comment: Well good you found an answer, but hard to guess this from the question - also it's a bit odd they do accept 127.0.0.1 but not localhost, so the bit.ly method explained in the blog will probably prove more solid in the long run.

Comment: Yeah I guess that would future proof it a bit, I hope. ;)

Comment: As this is the correct answer I suggest you accept it, as explained in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: josef's problem was not related to the absence of internet access to his local server, see his own answer for what was going on and a solution.  This answer handles the case where a local server needs to be visible from the internet.

localhost, aka 127.0.0.1 is the name that on each computer points to the computer itself. So Twitter looks at itself, obviously doesn't see the service, end of story.

If your computer is connected to a local network, most likely that network is NATed and using private addresses like 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x or 172.16x.x.x.  These addresses are private (not known outside of the local network because not routed on the internet), so that doesn't help you either.

What remains is your public IP address, ie the address your router gets from your ISP.  Via DNS you can map that address to a name, a free service that allows you to map a fixed **name** also to a variable **address** is [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.org).

But wait, there is more!  Your router protects your network by not allowing traffic originating OUTSIDE the private network IN, unless you define some forwarding rule in the router, in your case a rule that forwards incoming tcp traffic on port 9000 to your machine's port 9000.

Once all that has been taken care of, your computer will be accessible from the outside, and your callback should work.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not answering the question :(

Answer (score 1):

The reason that twitter can't use localhost as a callback url is because localhost is a redirect to your computers loopback interface. In other words, localhost is **always** the computer that you're on. In order for other computers (including twitter) to access your host, you need to use an external IP address, or a hostname.

To get your IP address, visit [whatsmyip](http://www.whatsmyip.org/). This will tell you your external IP address (which other computers on the internet can access). If you have a static IP address, you can purchase a domain name, or get a free one from something like no-ip or dyndns to make it easier to remember and type. You'll need to point a DNS record from that domain to your IP. You'll also probably need to do some port forwarding and stuff to get it to go to your computer on port 9000, rather than your router (dependent on your network setup).

Possibly an easier option would be to obtain a free hosting/domain service whilst you're testing.

Comment: Redirects should work, even to localhost. The thing to remember is that when a HTTP response header contains a 302 redirect, it doesn't care about where it is. It's like a fire and forget missile that tells your browser to point there, no matter what it is. Twitter never tries to directly access or ping the address.

Answer (score -1):

Edit your `hosts` file and add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 mylocal.loc
```

For Windows, it is located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\`. On *nix, you can find it in `/etc`.

Comment: This won't work for http://localhost:9000 as in the original question though. The hosts file doesn't really deal with port numbers.